# Infinite Loop on script binary

Tags: c, linux, buffer, infinite-loop

I noticed that we can get an infinite loop on the script binary by running

```
script -c "repeat 1000 ls -l && cat typescript"
```

I did it by forcing the script to flush is buffer into the typescript file (that's why the repeat 1000)
Then when the cat command outputs the file while the script binary is writing his buffer when it is full to the file : The "latency" between the output of the cat command and the writing of the file is positive and my question is : How to  make it negative, to make this infinite loop disappear ?

Of course with no environment modifications. I've got my own version of it in C that have the same behavior. Thanks !

Comment: Can you clarify why you are appending the contents of a file to itself?  It's actually not that surprising that it would proceed infinitely... If you only want to copy the file's contents as they existed at the beginning of your script, then append to that, why don't you explicitly copy the file to a new file and append to that?

Comment: What's the goal? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: That is the behaviour of the standard script command (man script). So it logs what happens on the terminal..
Then I just want to be able to do whatever I want using this command